# equality of two continuous and periodic function

Tags: real-analysis

I need to solve the following problem.

Show that if $f$, $g$ : $\mathbb R$ → $\mathbb R$ are continuous, periodic and $\lim_{x→\infty}$ $(f(x) − g(x)) =
0$, then $f = g$.

I have only used the definition of convergence so far. (Unfortunately, I couldn't go further for almost an hour.) For all $\epsilon$ there exists $ r\in \mathbb R$ such that $|{f(x)-g(x)}|\le \epsilon$ for all $x\geq r$

will you give me some hint?

Comment: You have to use that they are periodic (so assume a period p>0, that means f(x) = f(x+p))

Comment: This is a duplicate.

Comment: I know the fact, but I failed to use it properly.

Comment: Then, may i ask you some related links? I couldn't find questions related to my problem.

Comment: @YoonJiWon I'm trying to locate it, but I don't feel confident. It has been asked at least twice, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p,q$ be periods of $f,g$, respectively.

If $\frac pq$ is rational, we can find a common period, then $f-g$ is perodic with that common period. The only continuous periodic functions with a limit at $\infty$ are the constant functions.

Remains the case that $\frac pq\notin \mathbb Q$.
Then the numbers $kp\bmod q$ with $k\in\mathbb N$ are dense in $[0,q]$, hence we find arbitrarily large $k$ such that $g(kp)\approx \inf g$ and also arbitrarily large $k$ such that $g(kp)\approx \sup g$. We conclude that for such $\inf g= -f(0)= \sup g$, hence $g$ is constant and we can reduce to the first case.